# Angular bind html from Html entities

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

How to encode a HTML entities and display the HTML ? I have attached sample fiddle along this ticket

Controller:-

```
angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize'])
.controller('foo', function($scope) {
    $scope.bar = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Lorem Ipsum&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Rooms&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt";
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['myapp']);
```

HTML :-

```
<div ng-controller="foo">

    <div ng-bind-html="bar"></div>

</div>
```

Output :-

```
<p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b> <br />There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.</p><p><b>Rooms</b> <br />
```

Expected output :-

**Lorem Ipsum**

There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.

**Rooms**

Sample Js fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/68n89rj3/

Comment: Why can't you use `<>' rather than '&lt;' and `&gt;` ?

Comment: @TejinderSingh Actually that data came from backend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't working because your HTML is already encoded, so it just outputs the encoded html characters. What you need is to first decode the HTML before assigning it to the `$scope.bar` variable.

One way to do it is this:

```
$scope.bar = angular.element('<div>').html("&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Lorem Ipsum&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt;There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour.or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Rooms&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br /&gt").text();
```

It's a bit of a hack, where you first create an unparented `div`-element (so it only exists in memory), add your string as the html of this element, and finally extract the text. That should work for you.

---

Adding a filter to do it:

```
angular.module('app').filter('htmldecode', function(){
    return function(encodedHtml) {
        return angular.element('<div>').html(encodedHtml).text();
    };
});
```

and use it like this:

```
<div ng-bind-html="bar | htmldecode"></div>
```

Comment: It's working fine. IS there is any other solutions is available in HTML file itself?

Comment: Not really. But you could write a filter to do it for you, although that way it'd be re-decoded each time the element is recompiled by angular. I've included such a filter, although I still recommend you decode this only once, in the controller.